# C++ socket server on Mac. Help!

Tags: c++, macos, sockets, operating-system

I'm planning on writing a socket server in C++ running on a Mac. I've been searching through a great portion of the internet without any results. Anyone knows where to start? Or even got a basic source code?
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

i think the ASIO Library is platform independent enough for that.

Look here:
[Boost Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)
[Asio Only](http://think-async.com/Asio/)

Answer (score 1):

http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/

The above may be a good place to start - good easy intro to the sockets API with code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the mac has a unix-oid back-end (derived from the BSD family) any unix resource like [Beej's guide to sockets](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) should be applicable.  Also, a unix network programming book like [the one written by the late W. Richard Stevens](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss_gw?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=unix+network+programming&x=0&y=0) is a good resource,  His books on the subject are amongst the best in print and regarded as classic works on the subject.